# Using for loop to iterate through two groups of selectors (querySelectorAll)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through 2 groups of HTML elements using `querySelectorAll`, and apply click handler to matching indices (sorry if that's confusing).

Below is the code.

`campaignSelect` and `campaignDetails` each have 6 divs, and what I'm trying to do is, when `campaignSelect[i]` is clicked, a class added to `campaignDetails[i]` of the same index.

When I run the below code, I get "Can't read property 'classList' of undefined". This works however, if I use the actual index `campaignSelect[0]` and `campaignDetails[0]`. What am I doing wrong in the for loop?

Thanks!

```
var campaignSelect = document.querySelectorAll(".campaign-select");
var campaignInfo = document.querySelector(".campaign-info-container");
var campaignDetails = document.querySelectorAll(".campaign-details");

for(i=0;i<campaignSelect.length;i++){
    campaignSelect[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        campaignInfo.classList.add("campaign-info-active");
        campaignDetails[i].classList.add("campaign-details-active");
    });
}
```

Comment: Side note: Unless you've declared `i` somewhere you haven't shown, your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) *(that's a post on my anemic little blog)*. Declare your variables. :-)

Comment: wow thank you TJ, the second time you've saved me! :)